# Join multiple tables by multiple grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, query-optimization

We have a passing control system and every pass action is stored `Event` table in `MSSQL Server`. We want to join multiple tables with the `Event` table according to their relations as shown on the image below. However, I am not sure if the grouping approach that I used is correct or not because the query takes a lot of time. Could you please clarify me oh how to join these tables by multiple grouping? Here is the `JOIN` clause I used:

```
SELECT t.CardNo, t.EventTime, t1.EmployeeName, 
    t1.Status, t2.EventCH, t3.DoorName, t4.JobName, t5.DeptName 
FROM Event t 

LEFT JOIN Employee AS t1 ON t.EmployeeID = t1.ID 
LEFT JOIN EventType AS t2 ON t.EventTypeID = t2.ID 
LEFT JOIN Door AS t3 ON t.DoorID = t3.ID 
LEFT JOIN Job AS t4 ON t1.JobID = t4.ID 
LEFT JOIN Department AS t5 ON t1.DepartmentID = t5.ID

ORDER BY t.EventID Desc
```

[image]

**Update:** Posted execution plan below:

[image]

Comment: The query looks correct to me.  What is your problem?

Comment: It takes too long time. Actually I see the result at the first second (the results are retrieved step by step below the query in SQL Server Management Studio by pulling scroll bar to below). But the query takes 29 seconds and it seems to be to high for 125000 records with 8 column. Are you sure that is there any logical mistake on the query? I am not sure if the grouping order is correct (**maybe it would be better to group left 3 tables and right 3 tables and then join these 2 groups**). Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any indices set up on these tables?  This doesn't sound impossible to me given that you have 100K+ records and so many joins.

Comment: `EventType` - inner join, `Door` - I guess inner join also, `Employee`+dep+job - at least a subquery with inner joins, but if event is occured under employee context only - then all joins in the query have to be `inner`. And review your **actual execution plan**.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just want to be sure 2 things. 1) Is the JOIN clause correct or would it be better for this status? 2) Is there another steps that can be applied besides updating the query i.e. indexing tables, etc. If so, could you clarify a little bit more?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Coud you please post the updated query that you mentioned? It would be better not only for me, also others if you post it as answer and emphasize the part that should be revised. Thanks.

Comment: Two persons already mentioned **indexes** and **execution plan**. What do you want me to post? Same query with `LEFT JOIN`s changed to `INNER JOIN`s? Push button "include actual execution plan" and post your picture here.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Actually I have never used CTE and wanted to see it to be applied to my query :( On the other hand, I added execution plan above. Thanks...

Comment: I tried to apply the CTE method mentioned on [SQL Server – Multiple CTE in One SELECT Statement Query](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/08/sql-server-multiple-cte-in-one-select-statement-query/) but not succeeded... Any idea please???

Comment: CTE?.. So you have no indexes at all except primary keys, right?

Comment: Try to replace `LEFT` with `INNER`, watch how execution plan will change. Build index for every foreign key column - review execution plan again. Try with left joins and indexes - review plan again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey have you tried creating two CTE's to group the joins?

So in one CTE create a join for Employee, Department and Job. 
For the other CTE create a join for Event, Eventtype and Door. Then in the end, join the two CTE's using Employee ID and ID.

Aggregating the joined tables together might be quicker than doing the joins all in one go. By the way, hows the unique constraint for each table?

```
;WITH a AS

(
SELECT
    t1.ID
   ,t1.EmployeeName
   ,t1.Status
   ,t4.JobName
   ,t5.DeptName
FROM
    Employee t1
LEFT JOIN Job t4
    ON t1.JobID = t4.ID
LEFT JOIN Department t5
    ON t1.DepartmentID = t5.ID
)
,b AS
(
SELECT
    t.EmployeeID
   ,t.CardNo
   ,t.EventTime
   ,t2.EventCH
   ,t3.DoorName
FROM
    [Event] t
LEFT JOIN EventType t2
    ON t.EventTypeID = t2.ID
LEFT JOIN Door t3
    ON t.DoorID = t3.ID 
)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    b
LEFT JOIN a
    ON b.EmployeeID = a.ID
```

Comment: That is exactly I asked on my comment above ("... maybe it would be better to group left 3 tables and right 3 tables and then join these 2 groups"). So, could you please update your answer by adding the updated query according to your recommendations above?

Comment: On the other hand, I do not understand what you meant with "... hows the unique constraint for each table?". Could you explain a little bit more please?

Comment: I've updated my comment, have a try :). When doing joins always make sure that you have unique columns set out i.e. make sure ID is unique in Employee table and so forth or else you may introduce duplicates when you join to another table.

Comment: That is exactly what I have looked for and with this **CTE approach the query time down to 4 seconds from 30 seconds** :) Thanks a lot...

Comment: good to hear :), by the way just looked at the code, b should be left joining to a. I've switched it around for you. Saw from your original post that Event table was the one you are left joining from.

Comment: Thanks for updating. I liked CTE approach :)

Answer (score 0):

The query in your question is not representative of the query in the query plan.  In particular, it has the condition

```
RIGHT(t.cardno, 8) = RIGHT(t1.cardno, 8)
```

The use of functions precludes the use of indexes for the plan.

My suggestion is to add a virtual column to each table, index that, and then use that in the join:

```
alter table tEvent add cardno8 as RIGHT(cardno, 8);
alter table tEmployee add cardno8 as RIGHT(cardno, 8);

create index idx_tEvent_cardno8 tEvent(cardno8);
create index idx_tEmployee_cardno8 tEmployee(cardno8);
```

This should help the performance, if you change the comparison to:

```
on t.cardno8 = t1.cardno8
```

In addition, your query has no `WHERE` clause, so it is (presumably) processing a lot of data.

Comment: Actually I modified my query in order to brevity, but there is another problem with the indexes. Normally I should use PK-FK in order to joining and Employee tables, but as there is no data in the EmployeeID in Event table, I have to use CardNo field (also RIGHT method as the digit numbers are not equal). On the other hand when trying to create index, I encounter errors with your code. So, I have 2 question regarding to this issue. Could you clarify me please?

Comment: **1)** Should we use index such a kind of situation i.e. when we have to use a field (i.e. CardNo) except from PK-FK for joinining tables? If so, could you examine the code above?
**2)** By altering table and adding cardno8, will there be any problem with this virtual column? Thanks...