# Using Index for joining two tables when FK field is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, indexing, common-table-expression

We started to maintain a new project that uses SQL Server and there are some problems regarding to the data in some tables as explained below. There are 2 tables called `Employee` and `Pass` and the `Pass` table keeps the in and out of every `Employee`.

**Employee**

```
|| ID       || Name       || CardNo ||
======================================
|| 1        || John       || 101    ||
|| 2        || Christof   || 102    ||
|| 3        || Jurgen     || 103    ||
|| 4        || Jose       || 104    ||
|| 5        || Mary       || 105    ||
```

**Pass**

```
|| ID       || EmployeeID || CardNo ||
======================================
|| 1        || NULL       || 101    ||
|| 2        || NULL       || 105    ||
|| 3        || NULL       || 103    ||
|| 4        || NULL       || 101    ||
|| 5        || NULL       || 102    ||
|| 6        || NULL       || 104    ||
|| 7        || NULL       || 104    ||
|| 8        || NULL       || 103    ||
|| 9        || NULL       || 105    ||
|| 10       || NULL       || 101    ||
```

On the other hand, as the `EmployeeID` column of the `Pass` table is empty for every pass, we have to use `CardNo` column in order to join two tables.

But using the `JOIN` clause as shown below causes the query to be executed more time and I think there might be a better way by using index, etc. instead of PK to optimize the query. We have tried to create index, but could not create for `CardNo` column.

Could you please clarify us on how to fix the problem? Thanks...

```
SELECT *  
FROM Pass p
LEFT JOIN Employee e ON RIGHT(e.CardNo, 8) = RIGHT(p.CardNo, 8) --I have to trim card no as the digit sizes are different
```

**Update :** 
I tried to apply the following scripts, but only this part is worked:

```
alter table Pass add cardno8 as RIGHT(CardNo, 8);
alter table Employee add cardno8 as RIGHT(CardNo, 8);
```

And this part gives error: "Column 'cardno8' in table 'Pass' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index."

```
create index idx_tEvent_cardno8 ON Pass(cardno8);
create index idx_tEmployee_cardno8 ON Employee (cardno8);
```

Any idea?

Comment: "We have tried to create index, but could not create for CardNo field."  Why not?  Did you get an error?  I see no obvious reason that you couldn't create such an index.

Comment: "I have to trim card no as the digit sizes are different" - `pass.cardno` is not equal to corresponding `employee.cardno`? can you show an example?

Comment: Unfortunatela Card Numbers are saved 11 digit to Employee while it saved 10 digit to Pass table leading zeros. For this reason I had to take the last 8 digits of card numbers.

Comment: You probably have to `cast()` the `right()` function to an appropriate type.

Comment: Do you mean that I just cast the CardNo field in the query without changing it's data type from varchar to int? On the other hand should I create index that you suggested before? Thanks.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is the performance of the query, then you simply need an index on `Employee(CardNo)`:

```
create index idx_employee_cardno on employee(cardno);
```

If you are interested in only one or two other columns (such as name or id), you can add them to the index after `cardno`.

The only reason that I can think of (apart from permissions) to explain why index creation would fail is that `cardno` has the wrong type.  To quote the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx):

> Columns that are of the large object (LOB) data types `ntext`, `text`,
>   `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)`, `varbinary(max)`, `xml`, or `image` cannot be
>   specified as key columns for an index.

That seems unlikely given the sample data.  If this is an issue, then change the type to something more appropriate (or use a computed column for the same purpose).

Also, your query should use qualified column names everywhere (or you'll get an error):

```
SELECT *
FROM Pass p LEFT JOIN
     Employee e
     ON e.CardNo = p.CardNo;
--------^
```

Comment: Many thanks for your helps. Actually this question is related to [Join multiple tables by multiple grouping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668526/join-multiple-tables-by-multiple-grouping/35668881?noredirect=1#comment59019450_35668881) and I just cretae a separate ticket as the problem is different. So, I voted ıp your answer on that question, but unfortunately could not create index. On the other hand, you saw on that question that there is another problem that makes me forcing t use RIGHT function.

Comment: I updated my question above, could you please clarify me step by step on which procedures should I follow to solve this problem? Thanks...

Comment: You are right, the problem is actually datatype of CardNo field (Varchar). So, that mean if it was int, we could create index and use as FK, **is that true?**

Comment: @hexadecimal . . . I think any types other than the ones mentioned in the documentation are suitable for an index.